# Attribute Error module 'tensor flow' has not attribute '__version__' and similar with 'keras'

Tags: python, tensorflow

When tried to run the .py file on terminal, an attribute error is encountered saying module 'tensorflow' has no attribute'**version**'
and similar error is encountered for attribute 'keras'

terminal:

> MacBook-Air:~ a$ python3 'Desktop/ML/Python/tf.py'
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "Desktop/ML/Python/tf.py", line 2, in
>
> print(tf.__version __)
>
> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute '__version __'

the same when tried in IDLE python interpretor works fine.

I've tried updating pip3 and tensorflow to the latest versions 18.1 and 1.12.0 respt.

pip3 list displays : tensorflow 1.12.0

CODE:

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.__version__)
```

Expected output

'1.12.0'

Comment: Because you've named your script `tf.py`. Rename it. You're masking the alias you've set for the module.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks for the suggestion, the code is working now.